# x in the bottom of equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation where $x$ in the bottom. It looks like this $\frac{A}{B+x\cdot C}=\frac{x}{2}$.

How to find $x$?

P.s. I'm new here. So, if something wrong in my question please let me know.

Comment: Try multiplying both sides with $(B+X\cdot C)$. Maybe you can solve it from there if you know how to deal with quadratic equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\frac{A}{B+x*C} = \frac x2$

You can pass $\frac x2$ to the other side, it gives you $\frac{A}{B+x*C} - \frac x2 = 0$

Now you simply put every term on the same denominator, by multiplying your left member by 2 (both upper and lower terms) and your right member by $B+x*C$ ; it gives you $\frac{2A}{2(B+x*C)} - \frac{x(B+x*C)}{2(B+x*C)} = 0$

You can now simplify it : $\frac{2A-x(B+x*C)}{2(B+x*C)} = 0$ (note that it only exists for $2(B+x*C) \neq 0$)

Finally, you should know that $\frac{2A-x(B+x*C)}{2(B+x*C)} = 0$ **ONLY IF** $2A-x(B+x*C) = 0$.

You can now solve it, but be sure to verify that your x isn't a solution of $2(B+x*C) = 0$, it would mean that you have a division by 0, which is impossible...

I hope I correctly solved your problem =)